# How i can get the members list from group contacts in outlook

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

How to get all members inside the group in contacts, the example below:
we have test784637@groups.outlook.com and i need an Api to get the members "test@email.com,test@mail.com".

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-graph/expand-group-member-from-hotmail-account/m-p/2857186

Comment: Removing office-js tag because this post isn't about an Office/Outlook add-in.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT is there anyway to get group members in office web add-ons ?

Comment: Currently, the feature to get group members, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions